# Accessing the DOM returns null in lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

Somewhat new to Salesforce. I have a lightning component that has an iframe in it. The component will be in the lightning communities.  There is a method in the controller that gets called once the iframe is loaded. For some reason I can't access any DOM elements, it's always null.  Here's an example snippet:

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
     <iframe src="/mypage" onload="{!c.iframeOnLoad}" class="myIframe" frameBorder="0"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({       
    iframeOnLoad: function(){
        try{
           customCss = document.getElementById('customCSS').innerHTML;
        }
        catch(ex){
           console.log(ex);
        }
    }
})
```

The customCss element is actually there but for some reason it's not getting it. If I put that js snippet in the browser console, it does get the innerHTML in that element. I hope that understands it.

Comment: Am I missing something cause I do not see an element with the id of customCSS in your example

Comment: It's outside of the component. It's the ID of the custom css that I set in the branding section of lightning communities.

Comment: @OpuLance You can't interact outside of your DOM as a matter of security. You must interact with your other elements using application events.

Comment: @sfdcfox Ya I just found out about the LockerService Security feature. Now I know why.

Answer (score 1):

DOM manipulation, due to this critical update "Enable Lightning LockerService Security", will be not more usable. Instead, you can use `component.set` and `component.get` lightning pure methods.